# How to add conditions to Where clause in SQL/VBA/Excel to avoid data type mismatch

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to select fields from database based on a date selection, but I am getting errors.

> data type mismatch
>
> error number : -2147467259

After checking my column Date, it seems that sometimes it may contain values that are not dates and maybe that's what is causing the error.

My were condition is like:

```
WHERE [ClipDate] >= #2000-10-10# AND [ClipDate] <= #2020-10-10#;
```

I tried to use `CVDATE` and `CDATE` but also both fails:

```
WHERE CVDate([ClipDate]) >= #2000-10-10# AND CVDate([ClipDate]) <= #2020-10-10#;
```

Is there a way to tell inside a `Where`, something like:

```
if isdate(ClipDate) then
    'WHERE CVDate([ClipDate]) >=
    '    #2000-10-10# AND CVDate([ClipDate]) <= 
else
    'Don't select the corresponding field.
```

Comment: try with adding `to_char(..date..)` in where clause

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried `WHERE [ClipDate] BETWEEN #2000-10-10# AND  #2020-10-10#;`  You will also need to make sure that the Date being returned from SQL is actually a Date format like `YYYY-MM-DD`, if it isnt you will need to convert the date format in your SQL String.

Comment: Yes already tried and it fails. How to convert it in my sql string? Tell me plz to give it a try and let u know

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja do you mean that I replace the CVDATE by To_char ?

Comment: Yes, coz the string format would handle invalid date formats too

Comment: ok i will try it tomorrow and let you know because my Excel is at work and today is OFF. let me know anything else I should change or only replace cvdate by to_char ? and if I did that, the result of my where will remain the same I mean the comparaison between dates will work properly ?